# How to turn off visjs active shadow box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a visjs graph in my web page (using Chrome v49).  Whenever I click on or hover over the graph a blue shadow box appears around it.  After looking at vis.css I assume this is controlled by this selector:

```
.vis-active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #86d5f8;
}
```

The only configuration option I found in the vis documentation was `clickToUse` but that does not cause the shadow box to disappear, regardless of value.

I have also tried specifying `.vis-active` in my own css, even using the browser's debug to set it as the element styles with no luck.

Lastly, in the browser debugger, going through all of the vis elements shows nothing to indicate that `.vis-active` is being applied, or any other stylings that would result in that shadowing.

How can I prevent visjs from showing this shadowing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that what you're seeing is Chrome's default "focus ring," which can be overridden by:

```
.vis-active:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: That did not work, but the idea that it might be something specific to chrome is a good point.  I'll try and experiment with other browsers to narrow it down, thanks!

Comment: I looked into chrome's focusing a bit more thanks to your suggestion.  While the specific code you included did not work, something very similar did: `.vis-network { outline: none; }` Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad I got you moving in the right direction. I see that I got the classname wrong: `.vis-active` vs. `.vis-network`, and it may be that `vis-network:focus` will turn off the focus ring when the element in question is in focus. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1:

The simplest way is to **unset** the box-shadow property in **vis.css** (do it in the vis.css, if you don't have the vis-active line in the vis.css file, then create the following in that). Unset like this:

```
.vis-active {
    box-shadow: unset;
}
```

### Option 2:

Or you can set the shadow blur and spread to 0, like this (in your example):

```
.vis-active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px #86d5f8; /* in this case, color doesn't matter, you can even omit it */
}
```

Or, set it to something else you want, e.g.:

```
.vis-active {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #af90c8;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px #af90c8;
}
```

Good luck!